# Ratio of scale factors during matter-radiation equality

Tags: cosmology, perturbation-theory

For the past few days I've been studying cosmology using Dodelson's book. I am now busy with chapter 8 and was making some exercises. However I got stuck with exercise 8.6 (2nd edition) which goes as follows: We define $a_H(k)$ to be the scale factor at which the wavenumber $k$ equals the comoving Hubble radius, so $k = a_H(a_H)$. We are asked to express the ratio $\frac{a_H}{a_{eq}}$ in terms of $k$ and $k_{eq}$, where $k_{eq} = a_{eq}H(a_{eq})$. The natural thing I did was writing down the following
$$\frac{a_H}{a_{eq}} = \frac{k}{H(a_H)}\frac{H(a_{eq})}{k_{eq}} = \frac{H(a_{eq})}{H(a_h)}\frac{k}{k_{eq}}$$
However I could not get any further since I do not know how to simplify $\frac{H(a_{eq})}{H(a_H)}$. Does anyone have a tip such that I could proceed with this problem?

Comment: Have you substituted the expressions for $H$? The ratio of $H$ should become a function of $a_H/a_\mathrm{eq}$, due to how simply $H(a_\mathrm{eq})$ is expressed.

Comment: @Sten yes I see that I could use the expression for $H$ which you gave in your previous answer on a different question of mine. However as the wavenumver $k$ goes to infinity the ratio of $a_H$ and $a_{eq}$ should become equal to $\frac{k_{eq}}{\sqrt{2}k}$, however I don't see that happening

Comment: It will -- just write out the equation and solve it for $a_H/a_\mathrm{eq}$.

Comment: @Sten I got that $\sqrt{\frac{a_H}{a_{eq}}} = \frac{k_{eq}}{\sqrt{2}k}$ is this correct since if this is the case the problem is wrong?

Comment: I used the fact that at small scales (large k) the radiation and dark energy contributions are negligible in comparison to the matter contributions.

Comment: It is not correct that radiation and dark energy are negligible at small scales. You can neglect dark energy at all scales because its energy density is negligible, but not radiation.